# Highcharts failing to load intermittently via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, highcharts

we are using Highcharts and get the following errors on an intermittent basis. There appears to be no reason we can see why this happens in Chrome:

```
Uncaught Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16
VM210:16 HighCharts was already loaded
VM210:25 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function
```

Highcharts is loaded in a base.html file that is included in Django with the following includes:

```
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
```

We've been struggling with this issue and have now added the following code to a html page that is ajax loaded:

```
if (window.Highcharts === undefined) {
    console.log("Highcharts is not loaded, fetching...");
    $.getScript("http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js", function () {
        alert("HighCharts was loaded");
    });
}
else {
    console.log("HighCharts was already loaded");
}
```

Seems to make no difference.

So I think the problem relates to the fact that the page is loaded from ajax. I've put in the above code following a read through of stackoverflow.

Thanks.

Paul

Comment: Did you load jQuery **before** Highcharts?

Comment: Error #16 means that you load highcharts.js multiple time. Have you a live demo of your webpage?

Comment: @FelisCatus Hi, I do load jQuery before highcharts.

Comment: Hi, we don't as it's behind a secure wall

Comment: Maybe better is using a django module: http://chartit.shutupandship.com./

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan is the module still maintained? Looks to be a little old?

Comment: Well Im not author of that, so I adivce to contact with their developers directly.

Comment: Thanks. I will and I will get support from HighCharts.

Answer (score 0):

In my case these "vm210" errors came from a pop-up blocker I had installed in Chrome.